# How does TnT (Goloboff et al., 2008) assign internal node labels?

Tags: python, phylogeny

I have used TnT v1.1 (Goloboff et al., 2008) to assign synapomorphies from a presence-absence matrix (PAM) to a phylogeny. TnT does not allow for internal node IDs or branch lengths and I need to use the branch lengths with the TnT data for statistical analyses. I have a huge dataset (>1000 taxa) so assigning branch lengths by hand would be tedious. TnT begins internal node naming based on the first species in the data file (eg if a datafile with 100 species is presented and Aspergillus flavus is the first species, then the node preceding A. flavus is annotated N101). TnT provides internal nodes in its ASCII tree but not in its output newick tree.

Does anyone know how I can either (a) get TnT to print out the internal nodes in a newick tree or how I can replicate TnTs naming procedure, preferably using python (ete2/ete3)?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found your post by chance.

> TnT does not allow for internal node IDs or branch lengths

That is incorrect, on both counts; TNT does allow for those.  You should make sure you have carefully read and understood the documentation of a program before making such a statement.

For branch lengths in newick format (on tree n), combine the "ttag" command with the "blength" command, followed by "export":

ttag-; ttag=; blength * n ; export > filename ;

The ttag command allows manipulating/concatenating tree labels.  E.g. if you set the tree-tags on and print a tree showing node numbers (with the "naked-" command) then the tags can be saved to a newick tree, with "tsave * filename" (to open the tree file) , followed by "save *" (to save the tags):

```
naked-; ttag=; tplot n; tsav * con ; sav*;
```

ALL of this is explained in the online help of TNT.

As TNT also allows handling (via scripting) the values of branch lengths, node numbers, etc., you can probably do a lot of what you need in TNT itself, without the need of Python or such.

As for internal node numbering, yes, TNT uses its own internal rule to make sure that two identical trees always have the same number for equivalent clades.  The rule is: number the root node as T (# of taxa), then begin numbering nodes down from the first taxon (starting with T+1, then T+2, T+n, until reaching root).  Move to next taxon, and begin descending towards root numbering successively, until you find either the root or a node to which a number has been assigned already.  In this way, you can reproduce the internal node numbering, should you need that for anything.

Comment: Hi Pablo, thank you so much for your detailed response. I may have been looking at an outdated help section. Do you have a link to the help section you are referring to? 
Also, when I use the "-apo" to plot synapomorphies I notice that not all character states get plotted to a branch. Do you know why this is, or if it is covered in the help section?
Thanks again!